# Error: control may reach end of non-void function in C - RecursiveSearch

Tags: c, controls

I cannot figure out why this error is happening: error: control may reach end of non-void function.

I understand that the error means that the function may reach the end without returning anything, but I cannot figure out how that might happen.

I am only passing a non-void array to the function, if that's any consolation.

Here is the code:

```
int recursivesearch(int values[], int lower, int upper, int value)
{
    int mid = (lower+upper)/2;
    if(lower>upper)
        return false;        
    if(value>values[mid])  
        recursivesearch(values,mid+1,upper,value);
    else if(value<values[mid])
        recursivesearch(values,lower,mid-1,value);
    else
        return mid;
}
```

As the last statement is just an 'else' condition, it would ensure a return, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your `if` and `else if` blocks, you don't actually return anything from them. You simply run the function and toss the returned value. You probably want `return recursivesearch(...)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

> As the last statement is just an 'else' condition, it would ensure a return, right?

Yes. But the problem is some where else in your code. Note that function's return type is int but you are returning nothing in both of `if` and `else if` statement. Change

```
if(value>values[mid])  
    recursivesearch(values,mid+1,upper,value);
else if(value<values[mid])
    recursivesearch(values,lower,mid-1,value);
```

to

```
if(value>values[mid])  
    return recursivesearch(values,mid+1,upper,value);
else if(value<values[mid])
    return recursivesearch(values,lower,mid-1,value);
```

See the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).